# How to get the directrory name in shell script

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables

I have a script which sets some environment variable to paths:

```
export VAR1=/home/xyz/DIR_IN_WHICH_THIS_FILE_EXISTS

export VAR2=$VAR1/abc/qwe

...
```

Can I use something to get the `DIR_IN_WHICH_THIS_FILE_EXISTS` so that if I run this script from anywhere(any path) in the machine, it would set the same values to `VAR1` depend on in which directory the script exists?

Please help

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are trying to do. Can you give an example of what you want to achieve? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you are interested about the path of the running script. If so, you should use [`dirname`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname):

```
export VAR1=$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")
```

where `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` refers to the name of the curent running script.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, I think you need the backticked output of pwd (print working directory)

Thus try:

```
export VAR1=`pwd`
```